# Make the showModalBottomSheet() height adjust according to content

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make the height of the showModalBottomSheet() automatically adjust to the content.

I've used `FractionallySizedBox` with `isScrollControlled: true` but it need `heightFactor` to be provided.

Is there any way to adjust the height of the bottom sheet based on the content inside it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it with SingleChildScrollView:

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      //isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            
          ],
        ));
      },
    );
```

Comment: I don't want it to be scrollable. I want it to adjust its height.

Comment: in this way the height is flexible too

Comment: Thank you!! You saved my day.

Answer (score 6):

1. set `isScrollControlled`  to `true`;
2. set column's `mainAxisSize` to `min`;
3. set listView's `shrinkWrap` to `true`.

**eg:**

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
  isScrollControlled: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.green),
        Container(width: 300, height: 500, color: Colors.red),
        Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.orange),
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

[image]